# Random image selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following and its not working. The point is to show any of the 4 images below randomly every time browser refreshes. Any help?

https://jsfiddle.net/benjones337/690zc6h8/

Html:

```
<p>
  <img id="image" />
</p>
```

JS:

```
function Randomize() {
  var images = ["http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-18.jpg",
              "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-19.jpg",
              "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-20.jpg",
              "http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-17.jpg"];

  var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  document.getElementById("divid").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";
}

window.onload = Randomize;
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle has a few issues.  1) Your JavaScript code is *already* inside an `onload` handler.  Use the gear to change it to `<head>`  2) You never added a `<div id="divid">`, so your `getElementById` returns nothing.  3) You need to add some CSS to make the `<div>` visible, like: `div{ width: 200px; height: 200px; }`.  4) Your images need to be `https` (since the rest of the page is too).

Answer (score 8):

First: You need a div with the id `divid`.

Second: jsfiddle loads in https and the images load in http so the browser doesnt allow it.

Third: jsfiddle already runs onload -- so your code wont run.

Fourth: I added some css to the div so that the background image shows up.

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2nxm19fh/

```
function Randomize() {
  var images = [
    "//static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-18.jpg",
    "//static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-19.jpg",
    "//static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-20.jpg",
    "//static.ddmcdn.com/gif/lightning-gallery-17.jpg"
  ];
  var imageNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  document.getElementById("divid").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[imageNum] + "')";
}

Randomize();
```

Comment: Also Thanks for the help

Comment: How would i specify the image width/size? right now I am just specify the size of the div tag

Comment: Using background size in css maybe? @BenjaminJones

Comment: Happy to help @BenjaminJones :-)